# popup moving out of screen of mobile when i focus on input box inside popup

Tags: jquery

I am designing a website for mobile phones.It contains popup. when i
 focus on input box, sometimes popup going outside of screen(from top)
 and sometimes stay in middle.I designing website for mobile for the first time. i dont know
 how to handle it. Here the code i m using for opening of popup.

JS:

```
$("#voucher").fancybox({
        'titlePosition':'inside',
        'transitionIn':'none',
        'transitionOut':'none'
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="voch_txt specific_sprite">Got a voucher, <a id="voucher" href="#inline2">apply it here</a></div>
    <div class="hide">
      <form action="" method="get">
        <div id="inline2">
          <h3 class="vocuher_icon">Apply Voucher</h3>
          <div class="lightbox_col">
            <input name="" class="vocuher_input" value="" type="text"
                   placeholder="Enter 16 digit voucher code here" >                    
            <input value="update my cart total"
                   type="button">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

For viewport I'm using in head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Comment: why are you using fancybox? JQM isn't helping?

Comment: i m new to it. I have eperience in jquery for websites. So i implemented it in mobile. It will be helpful if you provide me some reference guide for jqm.

Comment: Try using jquery mobile popup. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/popup/

Answer (score 0):

Try this viewport.
Setting maximum scale and user-scalable doesnt zoom and scale the page.

```
<meta name="viewport"
    content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no' />
```

Comment: Yes, i have implemented it also. But it disable whole zoom functionality , I think its not good idea.